# Retrieve geo-coordinates from d3-tile

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to return [x,y] geo coordinates on a geo tile map. If you look in the console log on the following [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Guill84/vjL0ohet/2/) you will see they are coming out wrong. I am using the projection.invert() function, which I assume works backwards from the pixels to get back to the geo coordinates ... what am I doing wrong?

This is the bit of code that tries to seize the coordinates:

```
function mousemoved() {
  console.log(formatLocation(projection.invert(d3.mouse(this)), d3.zoomTransform(this).k));
}

function formatLocation(p, k) {
  var format = d3.format("." + Math.floor(Math.log(k) / 2 - 2) + "f");
  return (p[1] < 0 ? format(-p[1]) + "°S" : format(p[1]) + "°N") + " "
       + (p[0] < 0 ? format(-p[0]) + "°W" : format(p[0]) + "°E");
}
```

Comment: Am guessing the dude who downvoted this knows the answer to the question ... :)

Comment: Didn't down vote, but might have an answer for this (I find the d3-tile projection a bit of a run-around, inverting it will probably require a bit of run around too).

Comment: Hello Andrew. I've been struggling with the projection on D3 Tiles. I raised another question that is similar on here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50891330/cannot-get-labels-to-work-with-d3-tile-projection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D3-tile examples (and your fiddle) that I'm aware of (including most of the examples in the d3-tile documentation) generally use a projection scale of 1/tau (and no projection translate values) which would draw the earth within the space of a single pixel.

```
var projection = d3.geoMercator()
    .scale(1 / tau)
    .translate([0, 0]);
```

While the projection converts the 3 dimensional latitude/longitude pairs to Cartesian coordinates, a d3-zoom does all the scaling and translating to fill the map dimensions. This zoom must be accounted for when inverting mouse coordinates to long/lat pairs.

So to get the latitude/longitude pairs of a point on the svg, we need to backtrack. First we need to get the mouse coordinate if we were to invert the zoom, and then we can invert the projection:

```
var transform = d3.zoomTransform(svg.node()); // get the current zoom
var xy = transform.invert(d3.mouse(this));    
var longlat = projection.invert(xy);
```

*(See also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50244226/7106086) on transform.invert())*

Here's an [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3v28xc05/).

Comment: Thanks Andrew - this is a very complete answer. I see this has also been the subject of a debate on here https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/issues/37 and that other peeps have been struggling to understand how the projection works in d3-tiles.